# CKEditor post Issue in Codeigniter, tags are trimmed

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, form-submit, trim

I'm working on a project with CodeIgniter, on my localhost on latest version of [wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com) on w7 enterprise x64 SP1 with google chrome 14.0.803.0 dev-m, and added CKeditor 3.6.1 following [this guide](http://nukium.com/developpement-php/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/).

There's a weird issue I'm suffering with, hope you can help me.

When I post data, it's sort of "trimmed". I mean, before I submit the form, the content on the textarea when I press source code on ckeditor is this:

```
<p>
    <span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span style="background-color:#ffff00;">foobar</span></span></span></p>
```

But after the post, it becomes this (got the code using `die("<pre>".print_r($_POST)."</pre>")` at the very top of my posting method and viewing source code, same is added to database):

```
<p>

 <span>span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span>foobar</span></span></span></p>
```

Why `<span>` turns into `<span>span` ? How can I fix this ?

p.s: would you suggest TinyMCE instead of CKeditor ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That guide is only really useful if you need different configurations for the editor. You don't have to use CI to add an editor to a page. Have you tried just adding the editor in the "normal" way using just a bit of javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have XSS filter turned on in the config file? It removes some "illegal" tags from your POST input.

If yes, turn it off and try again. If your problem is fixed you now know where the problem lies. Now you only need to turn back on the XSS filter and find a way to bypass the XSS filter for the CKEditor field.

I used this method:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/186100/#919438